# MySQL: exclude if some column contains value for some_id X

Tags: mysql

Heey all, I'm struggling with something very simple but I cant find the correct query.

I have this table

```
id | col_a | col_b
----------------- 
1  |  1    | value_a
2  |  1    | value_b
3  |  1    | value_c
4  |  2    | value_a
5  |  2    | value_b
6  |  3    | value_a
7  |  3    | value_b
```

What I want is all distinct values from col_a where none of the records where col_a is some_id has no "value_c" in col_b

so in the case I want to get following resultset

```
col_a
-----
2
3
```

because col_b has a "value_c" where col_a = 1 (record id:3)

so I basicly I'm not interested in the id of col_a if any record with that id contains "value_c" in col_b

I hope's clear

already thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "textbook solution" would probably be to use a `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col_a
FROM   mytable a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   mytable b
                   WHERE  a.col_a = b.col_a AND col_b = 'value_c')
```

But I think that grouping and counting the `value_c` instances would be a tad more elegant:

```
SELECT   col_a
FROM     mytbale
GROUP BY col_a
HAVING   COUNT(CASE col_b WHEN 'value_c' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks!! I agree that the second is more elegant. I noticed also a slight difference. The second one also contains NULL values and the first one not.